# ASP.NET MVC5 and DataTables for a beginner: what goes where?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

I've asked this question on the DataTables forum, but in the interest of getting quick feedback, I'm willing to endure some abuse, so I'm cross-posting here.

---

I'm just starting an adventure into ASP.NET MVC5, armed with web development skills firmly rooted in 1995.  After some effort, the basic CRUD application is working, and I'm proceeding to dress it up some.  The functionality that DataTables delivers seems to be a perfect fit.

What I understand about JavaScript could fit in a small comment block, but I can follow well formed instructions.  So when I found the documentation that said, "just add these three include lines and this one line of JS, and you're off and running," I thought it would be straightforward.  I did what I thought the instructions said, and nothing changed.  Doing more research, I found someone's project that creates bindings for MVC5 and DataTables 1.10, but the instructions are sparse ("easy" is only easy if you understand what they're telling you to do).

Beginning with the DataTables instructions ("just add these three lines..."), here's what I have:

```
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.js">
</script>

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table" id="products" >
    <tr>
        <th> @Html.DisplayName("Code")</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayName("Active")</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayName("Published")</th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductCode)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Active.Value)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Published.Value)</td>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID })</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Theoretically, all I need to add is one line:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#products').DataTable();
} );
```

What's missing (here's where my rudimentary understanding comes in) is WHERE to add it.  I've tried several places, and no change to the table is made.  The first place I tried was within the `script` tag for the third block:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.js">
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#products').DataTable();
} );</script>
```

Is that the right place? Am I identifying the target table correctly? Do I need to figure out how to implement the code found at https://github.com/ALMMa/datatables.mvc ?  Should I abandon all hope until I've mastered JavaScript?

Thanks for whatever help you can give me.

Cheers.

JD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It's working!!

So, here's what I had to do:

In `_Layout.cshtml` I added the following to the `head` tag:

```
<link href="~/Content/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="~/Content/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

In `BundleConfig.cs` I added the following lines:

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/datatables").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"));
```

Finally, at the bottom of `Index.cshtml` is the call to the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8">
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#products').DataTable();
    } );
</script>
```

I suspect that the `BundleConfig.cs` bits are redundant, but it's working, so I don't want to fool with trying to optimize it right now.

Cheers.

JD

Answer (score 5):

I too had a difficult time getting DataTables operational in MVC5. I was attempting to use it in the standard Index View that Scaffolding generates against a view model.  I was able to build a small prototype but not against the FOREACH generator for the table.
I entered many different JS and CSS code lines from suggested examples and also patched the BundleConfig. Still no joy.
The Index would present properly but not the features such as sortable columns.
Eventually that was resolved by exactly matching the count of columns in the header to the count of columns in the displayed table body. Notice that the Id column is not counted in the displayed columns. In my example there are 6 displayed columns and six headers.  But seven in the model with the Id column hidden. The Action Column also has a header.

By now there are JavaScript and css fragments all over the place. I wanted to clean it up for reuse.

I was able to partially correct the bundle. Then a skilled associate showed me how to properly deploy the bundle references solely in the Index Page not on the _Layout Page where it would be unnecessarily loaded on every page.

You will also see that there are no Version numbers in any of the paths. This is purposeful to allow JS, CSS and DataTable updates without changing the source code.

Make sure your Table Id specified in the `<table>` line exactly matches the value in the Javascript at the bottom with a # in front in the JS. When I was finished with this task there were no remaining JS of CSS lines in my pages. Try the following.

1. Download the Latest Bootstrap and DataTables from NuGet
2. Modify the RegisterBundles Code in the AppStart folder by adding

   ```
   //
       //  These are the DataTables bundles
       //  Be sure to activate them on the Page where they are needed or on _Layout 
       //
       bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/dataTables").Include(
                 "~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.js",
                 "~/Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"));

       bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/dataTables").Include(
                 "~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.css",
                 "~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"));
   ```
3. Then add references to the bundles at the Top and Bottom of the Index page.

At the head section of the Index Page

```
 @model IEnumerable<"Your Own Model">.PriceList>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/dataTables")


<h2>Price List</h2>
        <table id="table_id" class="table table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>                        
                    <th>
                        Product Ptr
                    </th>                        
                    <th>
                        Product Class
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Ver
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Year
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Description
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Action
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>  
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.PriceList_Id)

                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product_Pt)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductClass_Pt)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Version)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Year)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductDesc)
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.PriceList_Id }) |
                            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.PriceList_Id }) |
                            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.PriceList_Id })
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
@section scripts {

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/dataTables")

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table_id').DataTable();
    });

</script>
}
```

Comment: Searched for a while on this one...  Great answer.

Answer (score 2):

From W3C scripting spec:

> If the src has a URI value, user agents must ignore the element's contents and retrieve the script via the URI

What you want is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#products').dataTable();
    } );
</script>
```

NOTE: The casing on `.dataTable();`. I'd have to check but I think `.dataTable()` is the creation method and `.DataTable()` accesses the datatables object once created.

Good luck with datatables. I like it but the "just a few lines and it works!" quickly gives way to a complex API once you want to do anything beyond the basic.

Edit: Also, is this legal?

> src="//cdn.datatables.net.....

Do you not need the "http:"? I would have thought you do, but maybe not.

Comment: Thanks.  However, I put that in and get the following error at runtime:
 `Unhandled exception at line 42, column 9 in http://localhost:49961/

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'DataTable'`

I tried both ways: `dataTable()` and `DataTable()`  BTW, according to datatable.net, `DataTable()` is for v1.10 and later if I understand it correctly.

Comment: See my edit. I'm not sure you're actually including the datatables script?

Comment: I get the same error after adding `http:` to the front of each of those reference URIs.

Comment: Not sure then. The error really suggests that the datatables script is not loaded. It's hard to debug that from here.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues here...

1. Don't use `src` when you are putting scripting inside the `script` tag
2. Datatables uses elements `tbody` and `thead` to group and stylize things correctly. So those need added inside the `table` element
3. You have different numbers of `th` compared to the number of `td`. These need to match so all table data has a column it corresponds to
4. Group all your scripts at the bottom of your page to speed up the apparent page load time

This should work...

```
<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table" id="products">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> @Html.DisplayName("Code")</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayName("Active")</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayName("Published")</th>
            <th>Details</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model) 
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductCode)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Active.Value)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Published.Value)</td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID })</td>
           </tr>
        }
     </tbody>
</table>

<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8">
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#products').DataTable();
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: I implemented that and continue to get the error:
`Unhandled exception at line 238, column 9 in http://localhost:49961/

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'DataTable'`

I tried adding `http:` to the front side of the `src` URI paths to no avail.  I verified that the target is valid (I can open the targets in a browser).  And, not knowing JavaScript, I don't know how to search out what it's expecting to find.

Comment: You have something wrong elsewhere then. My code copied into JSFiddle works verbatim http://jsfiddle.net/h1bz35n2/

Comment: OK, that's good to know.  Knowing this place, it's some random firewall configuration.  Or I'm missing some critical library.  I'm probably out of my depth.

Comment: Can you give me a link to that Fiddle?  I just tried the code in JSFiddle and it fails, so maybe my clipboard isn't working... (?)

Comment: It's in my comment above.

Comment: OK, it turns out that in my JSFiddle, I was trying to separate code (use all three panels), per the "errors" displayed by the tool.  Now it works in JSFiddle, but not in VS.  I think the next step is to pursue the ALMMa library bindings.  http://jsfiddle.net/JDRay/dLjsgmyq/

Comment: To make sure you aren't running into any firewall issues, try pasting "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" and "http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.js" into your web browser. You should see all the javascript code on the page in plain text. If you get an error, then you are probably being blocked by the firewall. It sounds like DataTables isn't loading. I wouldn't worry about the ALMMa thing, you've got a far simpler issue of simply loading javascript with a `script` tag to solve first.

Comment: I had previously done that; it doesn't seem like a firewall issue, as both of those files load in a browser.  I've also tried saving the files locally, and that doesn't work.  And, yeah, the ALMMa thing has turned out to be such a pain that I've currently abandoned the whole concept in favor of the much-clunkier but working Microsoft table solution.  I'd love to get DataTables working, but even after a raft of help, I'm still encountering this crazy error that I have no way to troubleshoot.

Comment: More research turned up a suggestion to implement the Microsoft Web Optimization Toolkit via NuGet, which I've done.  Using that toolkit requires copying files locally, which I did.  However now I get an error that says `$ is undefined`, suggesting that the JQuery bit isn't working.  And I even have the JQuery NuGet package loaded. **-sigh-**

Comment: If you look at the JSFiddle and copy that directly into your page (with no other templates or layouts) then it should work. Remove the razor code you have, just make a table with dummy data.